# errors pulling key information from multiple excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop

I am attempting to write a macro in a workbook whose purpose is to display the key information from each of a set of excel files. the first column contains the name of the file which will be used in the code.

the code I have written so far should loop through the list of 11 file names in the summary sheet and pull the info called from cell E21 in each of those files and place it in cell Hx in the summary sheet.

I have had no luck getting it to work so far, my first error im getting is "invalid Qualifier" on the line that says "MySheet". I know that there are alot of other mistakes here as I have never attempted to write a sub that pulls from other closed workbooks.

My code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OEEsummmary()
Dim Gcell As Range
Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$
Dim myValue As Integer

    Dim x As Long
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range

MyPath = "L:\Manufacturing Engineering\Samuel Hatcher\"
x = 2

MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While MySheet.Range("A" & x).Value <> ""

    MyWB = MySheet.Range("A" & x).Txt
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB

    Set Gcell = ActiveSheet.Range("E21")
        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x)
        .Value = "Item"
        .Offset(7, 0).Value = Gcell.Value

        End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

    x = x + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Ive looked at what an invalid qualifier error is and i dont understand what i have wrong with that part of my code. Any help with this and any other blinding errors would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick clarification. 
You want to go to 11 closed Excel files an extract the value in cell E21 an put that value in cell H(1-11). The files are all in a static location that is not expected to change and the source value is not expected to change. Is that all correct?

Comment: Check out the docs on Type Hints for tips and best practices. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201608011651375766662

You're declaring the variables with a type hint instead of explicitly typing them (bad). I don't think it's causing your errors, but I'd definitely change it.

Comment: @viper941 these cells H(1-11) will always be the cells being pasted into, however the 11 files where this data is being pulled from change constantly. the goal is for this sheet to be used as a summary sheet so someone can check the key info off of each sheet w/o having to open all the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I see that's causing the `Invalid Qualifier` error is that you are declaring `MySheet` as a string, but trying to use it as a `Worksheet` object. Below I've declared it as a worksheet and set it to the `Activesheet`. I also changed the `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` reference to `MySheet`, which I think is what you want. Also changed `Txt` to `Text`:

```
Sub OEEsummmary()
Dim Gcell As Range
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$
Dim myValue As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range

MyPath = "L:\Manufacturing Engineering\Samuel Hatcher\"
x = 2
Set MySheet = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While MySheet.Range("A" & x).Value <> ""
    MyWB = MySheet.Range("A" & x).Text
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB
    Set Gcell = ActiveSheet.Range("E21")
        With MySheet.Range("A" & x)
            .Value = "Item"
            .Offset(7, 0).Value = Gcell.Value
        End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: this corrected somethings, now the issue is that the files will always be open on another computer so they are read only and the sub wont open it. how do i deal with that?

Comment: You're welcome. That sounds like a different question. Have you tried searching for an answer? If you have no luck, I'd try posting that question separately.

Comment: ill do some more research but thank you for the answer above that fixed my previous issue